# Prevent Firefox addons from opening update tabs

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I have lots of Firefox addons installed and sometimes, when one addon is updating itself, at the next start of Firefox it'll open a new tab with update info (e.g. NoScript does that).

Is there a way to prevent this? I don't mind update notifications but opening some webpage is too much intervention imho.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way disable this behavior for all extensions, since they are independent from each other and use their own code to display webpages. NoScript lets you disable this "feature" though. Uncheck `Display the release notes on updates` in the `Notifications` tab of the NoScript Options window.

[image: NoScript notifications]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and a "solution" that I found was to simply turn off automatic updates for those addons.  You can still update them manually whenever you like, and you'll probably still get those new tabs showing up after you do so, but it won't just happen unexpectedly and interrupt what you were doing.